# "Fancy for fancy's sake"

Tags: expressions

I read that expression in a book, but that phrase didn't make much sense to me (at least not when trying to translate to Portuguese). I wonder if it's a common expression and what it exactly means. If possible application in one sentence.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether the **X for X's sake** trope originated with the phrase **art for art's sake**, but that's what immediately came to mind.

Wikipedia gives this origin of that phrase that I think is interesting:

> "Art for art's sake" is the usual English rendering of a French slogan
>   from the early 19th century, "l'art pour l'art", and expresses a
>   philosophy that the intrinsic value of art, and the only "true" art,
>   is divorced from any didactic, moral, politic, or utilitarian
>   function.

Fancy as a noun usually means something unreal or impractical, a flight of fancy. I guess that in the **fancy for fancy's sake** expression the meaning is adjectival: over-elaborate. I'm not sure the phrase in question is truly grammatical, but it's very expressive.

In passing: a rural railway station had some new automatic electric doors. The local staff had put up a helpful sign: "Fancy Doors", I think they considered the doors to be over-elaborate.

Comment: At the risk of sounding much less cultured than djna, an amusing example that sprung to my mind was, “Drinking for drinking’s sake.”  I am reminded of a 21st birthday party and the host’s mother bursting through the door at a late hour to announce, “Oh, go home everyone! You’re just drinking for drinking’s sake!”